# телеграмм бот, при запуске когда в тг пишешь город появляется ошибка TypeError: OWM.weather_manager() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, type-error, pyowm

```
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def send_echo(message):
        observation = owm.weather_manager(message.text)
        w = observation.weather
        temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']

        answer = 'В городе' + message.text + 'сейчас' + w.detailed_status + '\n'
        answer += 'Температура на сегодняшний час:',str(temp),'℃ ', '\n\n'

        if temp < -10:
            answer +='Сейчас холодно, зима на дворе, а что ты хотел?      ps. шапку накинь'

        elif temp < -5:
            answer +='на улице прохладно, без куртки не выходи'

    elif temp < -15:
        answer +='ЁмаЁ дубак на улице, теплее оденься'

    else:
        answer +='Темп норм, по крайней мере не зима)'
```

Comment: а что у вас в message.text, когда вы передаете его owm.weather_manager?

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно какую версию PyOWM вы используете. Но судя по документации к этой библиотеке, похоже что, вы используете ее неправильно.

Попробуйте заменить строку

```
observation = owm.weather_manager(message.text)
```

На следующие

```
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
```

Может, что и получится

Comment: Да, я пробовал ваш вариант, но при таком случае появляется следующая ошибка: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str

Comment: Видимо в этом случае доходит до строки ````answer += 'Температура на сегодняшний час:',str(temp),'℃ ', '\n\n'```` -а она у вас странная

Comment: Попробуй observation = owm.weather_manager().weather_at_place(message.text)

Comment: а блин, попробуй фстринг answer += f'Температура на сегодняшний час: {temp} ℃\n\n'

Comment: @VirbickasGytautas допишите это в отовет

Answer (score 0):

answer = 'В городе' + message.text + 'сейчас' + w.detailed_status + '\n'
answer += 'Температура на сегодняшний час:' + str(temp) + '℃ ' + '\n\n'

Comment: Это решает одну из проблем в вашем коде, но не проблему, описанную в заголовке.